# JIRA API return Bad Request for Worklog insert

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

I am trying to add a worklog for a issue in JIRA Software, but I just receive a Bad Request.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                                                        "Basic",
                                                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                                                                    convertStringtoByteArray(
                                                                                userName,
                                                                                userPassword)));


var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new
                {
                    comment = "I did some work here.",
                    started = "2017-08-17T10:52:10.475+0000",
                    timeSpentSeconds = 12000
                }; 

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var apiUrl = "https://<ACCOUNT>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{KEY}/worklog"
var result = httpClient .PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please provide a [MCVE](https://github.com/poqcommerce/Poq.API.V3/pull/749) and the community will likely be better placed to assist (e.g. `convertStringToByteArray` isn't provided)

Comment: If you use e.g. fiddler to look at the raw response you might get more information about what the error is

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your instance requires the `visibility` fields also.

As per the [Jira Rest API docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/issue-addWorklog)
sample request is:

```
{
    "comment": "I did some work here.",
    "visibility": {
        "type": "group",
        "value": "jira-developers"
     },
    "started": "2017-07-31T14:11:53.507+0000",
    "timeSpentSeconds": 12000
}
```

Can you add the `visibility` values and check ?

Answer (score 0):

The string conversion is the issue, please try like this

1. Prepare work log object using JObject

`JObject workLogObject = new JObject(
                                new JProperty("comment", jiraText),
                                new JProperty("started", strDate),
                                new JProperty("timeSpentSeconds", seconds));`

2. Create string with format option 

   `var workLogData = workLog.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
   var content = new StringContent(workLogData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`
3. Pass content 
   `var result = httpClient .PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;`